# Use subset of ES6 modules from a larger library in a web worker without bundling

Tags: javascript, web-worker, es6-modules

I have a library that uses ES6 Module imports, I want to move part of that library to a `Worker`.

This should be possible with new syntax `new Worker('worker.js', { type: 'module' })`, but *nothing* supports that.

Without that `import x from 'x.js'` and `const x = await import('x.js')` both produce errors.

I can use `importScripts('x.js')` to get an external script, but any `import` in that script will produce an error too.

Rollup or Webpack can bundle up all the referenced modules, but that creates new files to download and introduces a load of tooling complexity (as I already have `module` and `nomodule` targets and don't really want a 3rd).

- Is there any way to import an ES6 module into non-module JS?
- Is there any other way to get a class definition into a web worker?

Comment: Ordinarily I think people would likely be using webpack to transpile import statements into webpack's module loader format, where one bundle would be for your main app and another would be for the code going into your webworker, in which case `importScripts` would work for you. There would be some additional download overhead however, though you might be able to do some intelligent chunking

Comment: @Rhys I'm only using it for the legacy users (`nomodule` scripts) - modern browsers only get the modules they need instead of a bundle.